# Как отнять подстроку у ID элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу отнять подстроку у ID. Вот этот код выводит `NaN`:

```js
function someFunction(x) {
    var str = x.id;
    str = str - "Link";
    alert(str);
}
```

```html
<li><a id="myLink" onclick="someFunction(this)">Должно остаться только my</a></li>
```

Что я делаю не так? Есть ли решения лучше?

Comment: как ты думаешь, что ты делаешь вот тут: `+str` ? и как ты вообще представляешь себе арифметику строк?

Comment: @IsinMin а откуда отчаяние? Документации, справки, туториалы и прочее по работе со строками в JS никто не закрывал.

Comment: @IsinMin однако не запрещено создавать новую строку на базе существующей.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как удалить первую найденную цифру в строке с помощью JavaScript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/707200/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Получить строку путём удаления из ID первого вхождения строки `"Link"` можно так:

```js
function someFunction(x) {
    var str = x.id.replace("Link", "");
    console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<li><a id="myLink" onclick="someFunction(this)">Должно остаться только my</a></li>
```

Тот же вариант с `addEventListener` вместо `onclick`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        var str = event.target.id.replace("Link", "");
        console.log(str);
    });
});
```

```html
<li><a id="myLink">Должно остаться только my</a></li>
```

---

Для удаления всех вхождений `replace` можно изменить:

```
replace(/Link/g, "")
```

---

Вообще говоря, в данной ситуации с единственным элементом с ID `myLink` с тем же успехом можно было просто сделать `var str = "my";`. Поэтому, для полноты картины, вариант с несколькими ссылками:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("links");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
            var str = event.target.id.replace("Link", "");
            console.log(str);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a id="firstLink" class="links">Первая ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a id="secondLink" class="links">Вторая ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a id="thirdLink" class="links">Третья ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```

И, наконец, то же самое при использовании jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".links").on("click", function() {
        var str = this.id.replace("Link", "");
        console.log(str);
    });
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a id="firstLink" class="links">Первая ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a id="secondLink" class="links">Вторая ссылка</a></li>
    <li><a id="thirdLink" class="links">Третья ссылка</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот как вариант, но лучше так не делать вариант ниже с replace будет лучше

```js
function someFunction(x) {
    var str = x.id;
    str = str.substr(0,2);
    alert(str);
}
```

```html
<li><a id="myLink" onclick="someFunction(this)">Должно остаться только my</a></li>
```

Вариант по лучше. без учета регистра.

```js
function someFunction(x) {
    var str = x.id;
    str = str.replace(/Link/i, '');
    alert(str);
}
```

```html
<li><a id="myLInK" onclick="someFunction(this)">Должно остаться только my</a></li>
```

И наконец последний вариант с учетом регистра.

```js
function someFunction(x) {
    var str = x.id;
    str = str.replace('Link', '');
    alert(str);
}
```

```html
<li><a id="myLink" onclick="someFunction(this)">Должно остаться только my</a></li>
```