# Как удалить первую найденную цифру в строке с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, строки

Есть строка `var text = " Привет мир9! Сегодня 17 августа.";`

Как удалить первую найденную в этой строке цифру, чтобы получилась строка вида:

`" Привет мир! Сегодня 17 августа."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать `replace`
[Подробней здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Конкретно по вашему примеру:

```js
    var text = " Привет мир9! Сегодня 17 августа.";
    console.log(text.replace(/\d/, ''));
```